# Pixelize implementation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, filter

I'm searching for a way to implement a filter (similar to "Pixelize" filter in GIMP) in OpenCV.

https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-pixelize.html

What I've tried so far is to down and upsample the image by using `cv::resize(...)`.

```
cv::resize(*src, *trg, cv::Size(), perc, perc, flag);
cv::resize(*trg, *trg, cv::Size(src->size().width, src->size().height),flag);
```

The result is actually just a decrease in image quality.

Comment: Decrease in image quality (effective resolution) looks to be the same that's done by gimp: https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-pixelize.html  . use a smaller resized resolution and "inter nearest".

Comment: Pixelise actually blurs the image, if you reduce the image size, like you are doing or blur the image with a Gaussian blur, you'll get the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. reduce size (10 for ex) times.
2. restore size with: `resize(_inputImage, outImage, 
   Size(windth,height),0,0,INTER_NEAREST);`